# Can I extend deadline time for bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have asked  [Lie Groups/Lie algebras to algebraic groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832624/lie-groups-lie-algebras-to-algebraic-groups) on june 13th and kept bounty of 50 reputation 6 days back and it will expire in $23$ hours

I have received two answers for that and both are unsatisfactory..

Now the question is what happens to my bounty points?

I have seen in some other question that :

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 up votes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

As no answer has even one single upvote I guess bounty is not awarded to anyone..

I have requested the one who answered to edit that a bit to make it more accessible and he said  **I will think a bit on how I might edit the answer to make it more accessible**

So, i guess he needs some time and i do not want to go this bounty points offered to nobody...

I wanted to ask if there is any possibility that I can extend the deadline to say some three/four more days..

Answer (score 5):

After the bounty expires, you have a grace period of 24 hours to award it. During that time, the question doesn't appear in the featured tab anymore. If you don't award the bounty during the grace period, and no answer automatically qualifies for half the amount, the bounty is gone for good. There is no way to extend it.

What you can do, however, is start another bounty and award it if the edited answer turns out to be satisfactory. Keep in mind that you cannot start another 50 point bounty. It must be at least twice the amount of the previous bounty.

Comment: thank you for the info... :)